# Remove CLBeaconRegion from monitoring depending on current location

Tags: ios, geolocation, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, clbeaconregion

So I was looking for a way to remove a BeaconRegion from the monitored regions depending on how far it is from my current location.
I though I could use the center property, though I think I'm  missing something... Because the latitude/longitude values are like not valid...

```
po [region center]
(latitude = 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033891907065820605, longitude = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000059293723668713039)
```

How can I remove a BeaconRegion depending con currentLocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a CLBeaconRegion represents N bluetooth beacons with the same uuid. **an ibeacon  has no gps coordinate**. it has an RSSI value (the signal strength) and a 'calculated' proximity property but no location.

same as a wifi router ;) there are services to associate beacons/wifi routers with a GPS location but it isn't standard. how should the beacon know? :)

---

On IOS, the CLBeaconRegion class only has a center property because it is a subclass of CLRegion

**if YOU know the GPS locations of your regions use that data + your device's location**

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, you can stop monitoring `CLBeaconRegion`s depending on the user's location.**  But as you've discovered, the `center` property of this object won't help you do that (See @Daij-Djan's answer for an explanation as to why.)

**The typical way to do you want is to set up to receive significant location changes** using `CLLocationManager` at the same time as you set up beacon monitoring, like this:

```
[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

You then add a method like below to the `delegate` of your `CLLocationManager` to get callbacks each time the user changes locations significantly:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)locationManager
      didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
   CLLocation* location = [locations lastObject];
   NSLog(@"latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
          location.coordinate.latitude,
          location.coordinate.longitude);
   // TODO: change the monitored beacon regions depending on the
   // location.coordinate.latitude and location.coordinate.longitude     
   }
}
```

Note that you also need to make sure location services are authorized for your app for this to work and put a string corresponding to the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in your plist, but it is the same check you need to do to monitor for beacons anyway:

```
if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

See here for more details on signficant location changes:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html